# Raspberry Pi Green LED Always On

Tags: pi-3, raspbian-stretch, raspbian-lite

I was not able to find out why this error happens (repeatedly), please help me diagnose it.

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B, running Raspbian Stretch Lite (2018-11-13).

- It boots successfully.
- I can access and use it without any problem.
- After 90 minutes the resources are not overused: CPU below 5%, memory 115/927M, swap 0/100M.

After a while I can not connect to it via SSH, can't access the Plex server running on it. Both the green ACT LED and the red power LED are on constantly. I have to restart it manually, after that it is working again.

Previously I have used Raspbian, not Lite. It was not producing this issue. The hardware configuration is the same, I'm using the same charger (IKEA Koppla), external HDD, and it is on the same network. The charger's specification is the following: Total output of 3.4A, 17W. Maximum output per USB port: 2.4A. Voltage USB ports: 5Vdc, https://www.ikea.com/us/en/catalog/products/60415030/.

The only new software element is the No-IP DDNS updater: https://www.noip.com/support/knowledgebase/installing-the-linux-dynamic-update-client/

Could you please tell me how I can find out what the problem might be? Thank you!

Comment: If the green light is on the Pi is constantly reading/writing to the sd card. Is Plex or something else using all of the Pi's memory causing it to page memory to the sd card - effectively causing the Pi to grind to a halt?

Comment: After 90 minutes uptime neither the CPU nor the memory is used excessively. It is idle. I have no idea when it stops being responsive, only realizing when I can no longer connect to it.

Comment: What commands are you running to prove that? What power supply are you using?

Comment: I'm looking at `htop`. CPU below 5%, memory 115/927M, swap 0/100M. The charger is an IKEA Koppla charger. Before the Raspbian Lite I've been using the normal Raspbian, and it did not produce these symptoms.

Comment: Please edit your question and add these details. What spec is that Koppla charger - I always use the official RPi 5.1Volt 2.5Amp 18AWG cable power supply.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the question with these and also the only bigger software change I can think of: the DDNS updater that runs every 5 minutes. The charger's specification is the following:
Total output of 3.4A, 17W.
Maximum output per USB port: 2.4A.
Voltage USB ports: 5Vdc.
https://www.ikea.com/us/en/catalog/products/60415030/

Comment: have you checked any system logs at all for clues?

Comment: I see no evidence of a power problem **HOWEVER** The device states "Equipped with auto-detect function ‒ the USB charger detects the connected device and adjusts the power output accordingly" - this is **IMPOSSIBLE** with the Pi so who knows what it does.

Comment: Yes, I have checked the output of `journalctl`, but it only shows the logs of the current boot. I'll now configure it to persist the logs, so I can check back after the next freeze. Is there anything else I should check?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like Plex was doing something in the background and used way too much memory. I have reviewed every setting, removed automated preview/cover generation and automated library scanning. Since then I did not experience freezes like this.